# Nginx points to the incorrect folder location

Tags: nginx, web, nginx-location, static-content

I im trying to configure nginx to serve images on request. Consider the following config below;

**sites-available/images.conf**

```
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  localhost;

    location images {
        root html/uploads;
    }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
... ommitted ...
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}

    }
    ... ommitted ...
    include sites-available/*.conf;

}
...ommitted..
```

Now, when i try to access `http://localhost:8888/images`, it will output `404 Not Found` and the error logs

> 2018/09/01 17:01:30 [error] 10368#9796: *1
>   "C:\nginx-1.14.0/html/images/index.html" is not found (3: The system
>   cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost,
>   request: "GET /images/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8888"

Note that i have a folder inside html called "uploads". So i expected nginx to serve `C:\nginx-1.14.0/html/uploads/index.html` but it does not. I don't understand why it won't point to the correct folder which is `html/uploads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `nginx` URIs begin with a `/`, so your "images" location should be `location /images { ... }`.

If the URI `/images/foo` points to the file located at `.../html/uploads/foo`, you will need to use the `alias` directive instead of the `root` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location /images {
    alias html/uploads;
}
```